# User should be able to reset autoincrement (identity) column: possible solutions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In the app there should be a functionality for the user to reset orderNumber whenever needed. We are using SQL Server for db, .NET Core, Entity Framework, etc. I was wondering what is the most elegant way to achieve this?
Thought about making orderNumber `int, identity(1,1)`, and I've searched for `DBCC CHECKIDENT('tableName', RESEED, 0)`, but the latter introduces some permissions concerns (the user has to own the schema, be sysadmin, etc.).
EDIT: orderNumber is NOT a primary key, and duplicate values are not the problem. We should just let the user (once a year probably) reset the numbering of their orders to start from 1 again..
Any advice?

Comment: Use a `SEQUENCE` instead? This, however, sounds like a flaw. Your Order Number, presumably, is going to be your unique identifier, so "resetting" it is going to cause duplicate values to be generated, and thus `INSERT` failures; if that *really* what you want?

Comment: No, no, duplicate values are not the problem - the column is not the primary key, it's just the orderNumber user should be able to reset at any time. Will check the SEQUENCE, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain to use _why_ you want to do this? Almost certainly it is an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: `it's just the orderNumber` Yes, but surely duplicate order numbers are a bad thing?

Comment: Identity should not be used in the way you're suggesting. If order number is unique within customer, then sequence is not a good solution either. a

Comment: You could encapsulate the SQL in a proc and sign it with a certificate based on a certificate user with the necessary permissions. That way, users only need execute permissions in the proc. I suspect there are better solutions than identity here but there's not enough info in your question to suggest.

Comment: So, what benefit does resetting the order number have? What functionality does it provide? An Order Number, like an `IDENTITY` is an arbitrary identifier; it doesn't matter *what* it's value is. I would, however, suggest that it being unique *is* important. 2 customers having the same order number, or even the same customer having 2 *different* orders with the same order number is going to be confusing for all involved. Reseting the `IDENTITY` is not going to help maintain that uniqueness.

Comment: An identity column is used to uniquely "identi"fy a data set.

Comment: @Klamsi wrong, that's a `UNIQUE INDEX`/`UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`. An `IDENTITY` **does not** guarantee uniqueness. Provided that no one "messes" with the seed, then it *should* result in a continually ascending value, however, that on it's own doesn't make it `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Woudl a view using a `row_number` partitioned appropriately be the better choice?

Comment: From [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15), @Klamsi : *"The identity property on a column **does not guarantee** the following:

    **Uniqueness of the value** - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index."* Emphasis my own. An `IDENTITY` **does not** make a column `UNIQUE`, and it is explicitly documented is does. EF *might* "think"/"expect" a column defined as an `IDENTITY` to be unquie but that doesn't mean it is

Comment: @Larnu: I think I was wrong. It seems to be Oracle specific behavior for EF. With Oracle you only can have one identity column and it expects it to be the primary key. "...Only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' for properties that should not use 'Identity'."

Answer (score 0):

An identity column is used to auto-generate incremental values, so if you're relying on this column as the primary key or some unique identifer for rows, updating this can cause issues with duplicates.

It's difficult to recommend the best solution without knowing more about your use case, but I would consider (1) if this `orderNumber` should be the PK or would some surrogate key like (customerId, locationId, date) makes sense and allows you to more freely update `orderNumber` without impacts on data integrity, or (2) if keeping `orderNumber` as an identity make sense, but you could build a data model or table that maps multiple rows in this table to the same "order" allowing you to maintain the key on this base table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that orderNumber is a business layer concern - therefore I recommend a non-SQL solution.  You need C# code that generates the number for storage in your "Order" entity.  I wouldn't use IDENTITY() to implement/solve this.

The customer isn't going to reset anything in the DB, your code will do this.    You need a "take a number" service in your business layer and a place in the UI to reset it (presumable Per Customer).

Sql Server has Sequence.  My only concern regarding using it is partitioning per customer (an assumed requirement).  Will you have multiple customers?  If so, you probably can't have a single number generator.  Hence why I suggest a C# implementation (sure, you'll want to save the state as numbers are handed out).

Answer (score 0):

Identity should not be used in the way you're suggesting. Presumably you don't want a customer to get two different orders with the same order number (i.e., order number is unique within customer). If you don't care if customers get discontinuous order numbers, then you can use a sequence, but if you want continuous order numbers, then you would need to create an separate sequence for each customer, which is not a good solution either. I suggest you set the order number to **max([order number]) over(partition by [customer id]) + 1** on the insert. That will automatically give you the next order number for a particular customer.